# Unexpected resultset given?

Tags: python, append

Why does this program give an output of `[5,5,5,[1,3,'Hello','Barney']]` and not `5,5,5`?

```
aList=[1,3,"Hello","Barney"] 
bList=[5,5,5] 
aList.append(bList) 
if(5 in aList): 
 print(aList) 
else: 
 aList.pop().append(aList) 
print(bList)
```

Comment: Your code does `bList.append(aList)` in a slightly complicated manner.

Answer (score 2):

You **appended** `bList` to `aList`, then popped it off again and appended `aList` to `bList`.

Here is what happens step by step:

1. `aList.append(bList)` adds `bList` as a single value to `aList`; `aList` is now:

   ```
   >>> aList=[1,3,"Hello","Barney"] 
   >>> bList=[5,5,5] 
   >>> aList.append(bList) 
   >>> aList
   [1, 3, 'Hello', 'Barney', [5, 5, 5]]
   ```

   note the *nested* list; `list.append()` adds the argument as a single entry in the target list.
2. You then test if `5` is in `aList`; it is not, it is in a *nested* list:

   ```
   >>> 5 in aList
   False
   >>> 5 in aList[-1]
   True
   ```
3. The `else` branch uses `list.pop()` to remove the last element, which is a whole nested list, and appends `aList` to it; `bList` still refers to that last list:

   ```
   >>> temp = aList.pop()
   >>> temp
   [5, 5, 5]
   >>> temp is bList
   True
   >>> temp.append(aList)
   >>> bList
   [5, 5, 5, [1, 3, 'Hello', 'Barney']]
   ```

You probably wanted to **extend** `aList` instead, adding just the *elements* of `bList` to `aList`:

```
>>> aList=[1,3,"Hello","Barney"] 
>>> bList=[5,5,5] 
>>> aList.extend(bList)
>>> aList
[1, 3, 'Hello', 'Barney', 5, 5, 5]
```

Now `5 in aList` is `True`, and `bList` is not going to be affected.

Comment: I rarely see such well explained answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Because, `aList.pop()` actually returns `bList` and you are appending the contents of `aList` to it.